# Possible to force children on new line but keep child behavior like inline-block? See code for clarification

Tags: css

```html
<div class="content">
This is the content
  <span class="contentTag">
  #
    <span>tag1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="contentTag">
  #
    <span>tag2</span>
  </span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div>This is how I want it (can't change html structure though, pure css only)</div>
<span>#tag1</span>
<span>#tag2</span>
```

So I'm trying to style a website that I visit often by injecting css using a chrome extension. So I can't change the html structure and injecting js isn't practical as the site is heavily dependent on js and changes the markup often.

**Desired**

```
This is the content
#tag1 #tag2
```

I've been trying for the past half hour, but can't figure it out with just CSS. It has to stay dynamic though, since there might be more tags and they should all fit on the second line (within reason, of course if I had 20 tags it's going to go onto a third or maybe fourth line).

**Is this possible with just CSS?**

**EDIT!!!**

Sorry everyone. The markup is a little different. I didn't notice. Its updated above in the code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the before selector to the first child span like so:

```
.content span.contentTag:first-child:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's still pretty much the same. Keep in mind when you define things a bit more strongly vs. being generic it leaves less possibility for error. For example if someone decides to dump a span with special style into the first sentence before the tags the generic stuff is going to "blow up".

Comment: Thank You! It was driving me crazy! Gonna add this to my bag of tricks. Definitely useful to know

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: updated to match new markup
notice the immediate child selector

```css
.content > :first-child::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
This is the content
  <span class="contentTag">
  #
    <span>tag1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="contentTag">
  #
    <span>tag2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with :before you can do it

```css
.content :first-child::before {
  content: ''; display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
This is the content
  <span class="contentTag">#tag1</span>
  <span class="contentTag">#tag2</span>
</div>
```